# What are parameters are to be considered while selecting Battery Management System?

Tags: electrical-engineering, automotive-engineering, battery

what are factors to be considered while selecting bms? Does the BMS required change with cell chemistry and cell geometry? if yes, how does it depend. and also How do we determine the placement and no.of sensors required for a bms?

Comment: So what are the requirements for each chemistry you have considered so far? Add that so we don’t waste time duplicating effort.

Comment: BMS? Please be courteous & explain your abbreviations, don't assume everyone knows.